# Check SSD stability before returning it as broken?

Tags: ssd

I have the Transcend SSD 720 256GB 2,5" 7mm disk. And randomly I get disk IO errors in utorrent and large files copying to external will fail. I have removed it from my laptop since I need max stability. I use my laptop on exams. How can I really benchmark it/make-it-sweat whilst connected to my desktop? I want to re-create some of the fails as I need proof if I am to return it. Firmware is updated. BIOS on laptop is updated. I could just completely nul the disk and then check for bad sectors, but is there anything else I could use for testing?

Edit: It has 7 bad sector replacement operations. What does it mean?

Comment: What OS? What does SMART say?

Comment: Win7 x64 home premium, don't know. Disk is not in a computer. I will just try to nul it now.

Comment: Some bad sectors found. Care to comment @Bobby

Comment: Ask Transcend Support for an officially-supported utility to test the SSD to prove the problem. If there isn't one, ask what their return policy is. They might just need you to return the disk and they will check themselves and take action as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the tools [here](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=downloads), there's a whole slew of useful things such as testdisk.  Should
let you find most problems and maybe even suggest fixes.  I use this tool a lot on my new drives.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the "test" programs are on this page...

Comment: It's a live cd so you pop it in and boot from it.
list of the tools: http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=programs

Comment: Also, using an SSD is not very good for utorrent, especially if you are downloading massive amounts of files.  Mechanical harddrives are much better for that(at standard internet speeds).

Comment: Yes in the 100GB range, that could explain it. I backed up the drive, nulled it using secure delete via boot disk and reinstalled via win7 backup system. So far everything is perfect.